# Django: Access model as dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

I have data in a python dictionary that I'd like to store in a model instance. For example, my dictionary might look like

```
data = { 'date': '6/17/09', 'name': 'something', 'action': 'something' }
```

And my model might look like:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField()
    action = models.CharField()
```

I'm looking for a clean way to do something like this:

```
s = Something()
for k in data:
    s[k] = data[k]
```

[Update] Shortly after posting this I realized I probably just want to use the Django (de)serializer framework with the 'python' serializer. Ayman's answer is quite nice as well, let me think about which will work better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
data = {'date': '6/17/09', 'name': 'something', 'action': 'something'}
s = Something(**data)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
s = Something(date='6/17/09', name='something', action='something')
```

Comment: Nice, that's even more obvious.